# Complete POST and redirect to a third party site

Tags: c#, forms, post

I have been struggling with this for three days, I want to do a manual post to a third party provider, that will then take details from the web user (in this case the provider is PayFast) and then will redirect back to my site depending on the success or failure.

I have tried using a number of examples on this site and others including one that manually recreates the form as can be seen at (http://www.jigar.net/articles/viewhtmlcontent78.aspx) the main example that I find is similar to the post at stackoverflow questions 1167067

here is the result in my code, which seams to create the stream, but I cannot figure out how to send the control to the providers website since response.redirect kills the stream

```
string vystup = null;
//Our postvars
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pPostData);
//Initialisation, we use localhost, change if appliable
HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(PF_HOST);
//Our method is post, otherwise the buffer (postvars) would be useless
WebReq.Method = "POST";
//We use form contentType, for the postvars.
WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
//The length of the buffer (postvars) is used as contentlength.
WebReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
//We open a stream for writing the postvars
Stream PostData = WebReq.GetRequestStream();
//Now we write, and afterwards, we close. Closing is always important!
PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
PostData.Close();
//Get the response handle, we have no true response yet!
HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();
//Let's show some information about the response
PostResult = "=Status Code: " + WebResp.StatusCode ;
Console.WriteLine(WebResp.Server);

//Now, we read the response (the string), and output it.
Stream Answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader _Answer = new StreamReader(Answer);
vystup = _Answer.ReadToEnd();

PostResult = "redirect called...";

// Need to now send the post form to PayFast
```

Comment: What does "send the control to the providers website" mean?  The "WebReq.GetResponse()" line is already posting the data to the other site.

Comment: the browser is not getting sent to the site, if that is what WebReq.GetResponse() is supposed to do it is not working. 

So that is what I mean I wan the browser to be redirect to PF_HOST, if I do Response.Redirect(PF_HOST) then it redirects but there are no form vars

Comment: For reference 
const string PF_HOST = "https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/eng/process";

Comment: sorry did not use code
<code>
const string PF_HOST = "https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/eng/process";
</code>

Comment: Seem as though this thread is dead, I thought I would update what I have found. I ran the debugger, and looked at what was in WebResp, and found that in side ResponseUri was a page that said that you have reach this page beacuse you have press back button...

So I went back to the old normal &lt;from action=... and used that, and that works, so the url is correct and the data is correct - I use the same function to place values in the &lt;form is &lt;% =GetValue(x) %&gt; as I use to make the string pPostData that I pass to the routine above. So I am even more confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it,thanks to http://www.jigar.net/articles/viewhtmlcontent78.aspx

I created a new class as per the doc, and made a few tweaks, like initializing th URL as part of the declaration and it works like a charm, thanks to JigJar

I had found this solution before, and given up on it.